# Unity Prefabs missing after pulling project from GitHub

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, version-control, missing-data, prefab

I started to make a project on a Windows computer and uploaded it via GitHub. Later I wanted to download it on my Mac. But when I start the project on MacOS Unity the scene is empty and all prefabs are missing. Every time when I check GitHub it is deleting a lots of meta.files. When I discard the deletion, all meta.files are deleted again as soon as I start the project on my Mac.

Getting back to Windows GitHub says that everything is pushed. Referring to that article (https://medium.com/codex/solving-the-missing-prefab-issue-in-unity3d-ae5ba0a15ee9) the problem appears similar. But the solution does not help.

What is the problem to get my project from Windows to Mac via GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unity deletes .meta files":
After some research the answer to this seems to be - Unity removes .meta files when the corresponding object is missing.

"Prefabs are missing":
GitHub on my windows computer did not commit the .obj files. It took me a while to figure out that somehow a "gitignore_global.txt" was installed from somewhere (maybe GitHub Desktop?). .obj files were included to be ignored. That "gitignore_global.txt" is located in:[x:/User/Documents]

If you face the same problem - check the gitignore-file in your Unity project too. If certain file types are prohibited via one of these 2 files - no chance!

Cheers

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  It can be good to setup another computer (doesn't have to be a CI server) to try and build your project.  That way you'll know if anything is missing.